# valueChanges of FormArray control not triggering

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms, formarray

I am trying to capture the valueChanges event of FormArray control in angular 5 reactive form. I have normal form group valueChanges events and same work fine but doesn't work with formArray controls.

I have defined my form group as -

```
this.ApplicationForm = this.fb.group({
  ApplicationPenalties: this.fb.array([this.preparePenaltyDetails()])
});
```

and initializing form array as follows -

```
preparePenaltyDetails(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      Id: '',
      ApplicationId: '',
      RevisionNo: '',
      PenaltyMwh: ''
    });
  }
```

When I am getting data from my api, I am setting the control as -

```
this.ApplicationForm.setControl('ApplicationPenalties', this.fb.array(this.application.ApplicationPenalties
              .map(x => this.fb.group(x)) || []));
```

my html template is as follows -

```
<div formArrayName="ApplicationPenalties" *ngFor="let penalty of ApplicationPenalties.controls; let i=index">
                    <div [formGroupName]="i">
                      <div class="row pocCharges">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <h4 class="d-sm-block">Revision Number</h4>
                            <div class="input-group">
                              <input class="form-control form-control-sm" formControlName="RevisionNo" type="text">
                              <span class="input-group-addon">
                                <i class="material-icons">account_box</i>
                              </span>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <h4 class="d-sm-block">Penalty(MWh)</h4>
                            <div class="input-group">
                              <input class="form-control form-control-sm" formControlName="PenaltyMwh" type="number">
                              <span class="input-group-addon">
                                <i class="fa fa-bolt fa-2x"></i>
                              </span>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
```

and then in ngOnInit, I am trying to capture the valueChanges event -

```
(<FormArray>this.ApplicationForm.get('ApplicationPenalties')).controls.forEach(
      control => {
        control.get('PenaltyMwh').valueChanges
        .debounceTime(100)
        .distinctUntilChanged()
        .subscribe(value => console.log(value));
      }
    );
```

But it never get triggered. I also have tried to put the valueChanges code snippet in my formArray initialization but no luck,

Comment: Well, you subscribe to the valueChanges of your controls in ngOnInit, but later, when you get data from your API, you replace the form array and its controls by different ones. So I find it quite normal not to get any change from the old, obsolete, replaced controls. You probably want to change the **value** of the existing controls, rather than replacing them by new ones.

Comment: ok..thanks for quick response. Where should I check for valueChanges?

Comment: Wherever you want. That is irrelevant. Re-read my comment carefully.

Comment: Got it. Thank you

Comment: Just check this out https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dr6o5f

Comment: what if the formarray is having more than one formGroup and how to identify which one got update

Comment: you can check for that particular control.